# Biblatex : Editing the apa bibliography style

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, apa-style

I'm using `biblatex-apa`.
my problem is with the way biblatex displays web page references.
Biblatex displays the `urldate` before the `url`. I would like it to be the opposite.

here's how it looks now (it's French but I believe this is not so important)

> Duben, R. (2022). Conférences & ateliers. Consulté le 14/09/2022, **en ligne
> sur le site https://remydubern.com/conferences/**

and here's how I would like it to be something like :

> Duben, R. (2022). Conférences & ateliers. **En ligne
> sur le site https://remydubern.com/conferences/** Consulté le 14/09/2022

I tried to modify the `apa.bbx` which in my computer is located in `/opt/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex-apa/`.

I managed to change the order of the url and date, but not the "consulté le" and "En ligne sur le site" parts (this would be something like "retrieved" and "from" in Englishn ; these are translated via french-apa.lbx)

I believe my solution lies somewhere here. I had some success messing with `DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}` and `\renewbibmacro*{url+urldate}` but I just don't know how this thing works.

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\url{#1}\nopunct}

\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{%
  \bibstring{retrieved}\space#1%
  \urldatecomma\bibstring{from}}

\newbibmacro*{doi+url}{%
  \ifboolexpr{          test {\iffieldundef{doi}}
                 or not togl {bbx:doi}}
    {\ifboolexpr{       test {\iffieldundef{url}}
                 or not togl {bbx:url}}
       {\newunit}
       {\usebibmacro{url+urldate}%
        \setunit{\addspace}}}
    {\printfield{doi}%
     \setunit{\addspace}}}

\renewbibmacro*{url+urldate}{%
  \ifthenelse{\iffieldundef{url}\OR\NOT\iffieldundef{doi}}
    {}
    {\iffieldundef{urlyear}
      {}
      {\printurldate
       \setunit{\addspace}}%
     \printfield{url}}}
```

Here's my `.tex` file

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa,dateera=astronomical,seconds=true,urldate=short]{biblatex}
\bibliography{biblio.bib}
\setmainlanguage{french}

\begin{document}

\title{APA test}
\author{}
\date{}

\maketitle


\printbibliography
\nocite{*}

\end{document}
```

And here's an extract of my .bib

```
@online{duben_conferences_nodate,
    title = {Conférences \& ateliers},
    date = {2022},
    url = {https://remydubern.com/conferences/},
    author = {Duben, Remy},
    urldate = {2022-09-14},
    langid = {french},
}
```

I'm interested in any kind of solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Never** modify files from your TeX distribution like `/opt/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex-apa/` directly. Only work with renamed copies. If you modified the file already, it is not guaranteed that the following will work. If push comes to shove reinstall the relevant package `biblatex-apa` on your machine.

---

You want to reorder the calls to `\printfield` and `\usebibmacro` in the definition of the bibmacro `url+urldate`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa,dateera=astronomical,seconds=true,urldate=short]{biblatex}
\setmainlanguage{french}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{french}{
  urlfrom = {en ligne sur le site},
  urlseen = {consulté le},
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{%
  \bibstring{urlfrom}\space\url{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{%
  \bibstring{urlseen}\space#1}

\renewbibmacro*{url+urldate}{%
  \ifthenelse{\iffieldundef{url}\OR\NOT\iffieldundef{doi}}
    {}
    {\printfield{url}%
     \setunit{\addspace\bibsentence}%
     \printurldate}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{duben_conferences_nodate,
  title   = {Conférences \& ateliers},
  date    = {2022},
  url     = {https://remydubern.com/conferences/},
  author  = {Duben, Remy},
  urldate = {2022-09-14},
  langid  = {french},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\printbibliography
\nocite{*}
\end{document}
```

[image: Duben, R. (2022). Conférences & ateliers. En ligne sur le site https://remydubern.com/conferences/ Consulté le 14/09/2022.]